# Milliseconds convert and get year

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a BIGINT containing a date formatted in milliseconds. I'm looking to filter records by year of a selected column `created_at`. I'm using MYSQL as my database.

This is what I have so far in my controller.

```
@agent = Agent.where('Time.at(created_at/1000).year = ?', '2017')
```

Which provides the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database doesn't understand Ruby code like `Time.at(created_at/1000).year` so you can't use it in a `where` call like that, that form of `where` works with snippets of *SQL*, not *Ruby*.

You could let the database do the work of extracting the year from your "milliseconds since epoch" `created_at` value. You can do that in one step using MySQL's [`from_unixtime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function with the appropriate format string:

```
Agent.where("from_unixtime(created_at/1000, '%Y') = ?", '2017')
```

That reads almost the same as your attempt to send Ruby code to the database.

You may, of course, prefer to do the work in Ruby as in [Charlie Weems's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405203/479863) though.

If you're doing this a lot and there's nothing else in the WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows that you're looking at, you'll probably want to compare how each approach interacts with whatever indexes you have.

Comment: Both answers are solid. But this method suits my needs better. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know otherwise, I don't think you can do `Time.at` inside of a where comparison like that.

One approach would be to reverse the comparison, and turn the year into milliseconds since epoch:

```
comparison_time = (Time.new(2017, 1, 1).to_f * 1000).to_i
@agent = Agent.where("created_at = ?", comparison_time)
```

**Note:** If your rows are timestamped exactly to the year, you could use an equals comparison like in your example. Otherwise you'll likely need both a start date and end date so that you can return a range. Example:

```
start_time = (Time.new(2017, 1, 1).to_f * 1000).to_i
end_time = (Time.new(2018, 1, 1).to_f * 1000).to_i
@agent = Agent.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", start_time, end_time)
```

Another approach would be to loop through all of your agents, converting the created_at of each to a `DateTime` and comparing to 2017. However, if you have a large table this could take a significant amount of memory since Rails would be doing the operation as opposed to MySQL.